# Send HTML Form data Via PHP

Tags: php, html

can anybody help me fix my php code so that it will send the form data to the email address? i am using MAMP Server to check wether it works the website works as planned however once i fill the form out and press submit it takes me to the PHP page however no email is sent.

PHP CODE

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$emailSubject = 'Customer Has a Question!';
$webMaster = 'r1bos@hotmail.com';

$nameField = $_POST ['Full_Name'];
$emailField = $_POST['E-Mail'];
$phoneNumber = $_POST['Phone_Number'];
$questionField = $_POST ['Query'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Questions: $question <br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

@mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);  
exit; 



}     
?>
```

HTML FORM

```
 <form action="Php/form.php" method="post" name="Contact_Form" >

       <label for="fullname">Full Name: </label> 
       <input type="text" name="Full_Name" id="name"><br>

        <label for="E-Mail">E-Mail: </label>
       <input type="text" name="E-Mail" id="email" ><br>

        <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number: </label> 
       <input type="text" name="Phone_Number" id="phonenumber" ><br>

        <label for="Query">Query: </label> 
       <textarea name="Query" rows="4" cols="21" id="query" ></textarea><br>


       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" >

      </form>
```

Comment: `@mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);` — `@`!? Why are you suppressing errors if it doesn't work?!

Comment: Is `$_POST ['Full_Name'];` a typo? Same for `$_POST ['Query']`. Also, did you install / enable mail server on your MAMP? Also on a side note, `label for="<name>"`, the `<name>` should match your `input` fields `id`.

Comment: @Quentin he is probably using the code for which he doesn't know what it does exactly

Comment: i took out the @ and no errors are produced!

Comment: You should rather use `if(!empty($_POST['Full_Name'])) {` instead of `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`. Add to the beginning `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`. Also make an output if the if is not true `} else { echo 'nothing to be done'; }`.

Comment: Emails can be a real pain. After many years of having to troubleshoot why emails aren't sending / trying to find lost emails etc... I highly recommend just letting a service take care of your emails. Something like [Postmark](https://postmarkapp.com/) or [Mailgun (free)](http://www.mailgun.com/)